# angular universal cookie vanished

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, angular-universal

[angular2-universal - universal - common cookie](https://universal.angular.io/api/universal/index.html#_common_cookie_)

Check the above link and see that there is cookie API but I can't find it or able to add in the angular2 app. I checked the documentation and even google can't find it :/
Is it renamed or is there any other way to use it?

can anyone help me with jsfiddle or any example on how to use it?

Comment: what do you want to do with it?